# How to re-seed a table identity in SQL Server 2008 and undo it all safely?

Tags: sql-server-2008, seed

I need to do this for testing only, but then undo it when the test is done.

I have seen some tutorials online on how to re-seed a table, but not so much on how to undo it.

Let's say the table definition is the following:

```
create table beer
(
 beer_id  numeric(10) not null,
 mnemonic        nvarchar(8)
);
go
```

Let's say that I want the new identities to temporarily start at `12345`, and at the end delete the new rows and set the next identity to what it would have been.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The command to reset the identity property is

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (tablename, RESEED, new_reseed_value)
```

When you want to set the column identity to 12345 you run this

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (beer, RESEED, 12345)
```

When you want to delete test rows and restore the value to the previous value, you do the following.

```
DELETE
FROM beer
WHERE beer_id >= 12345 ;

DECLARE @NewSeed NUMERIC(10)
SELECT @NewSeed = MAX(beer_id)
FROM beer ;

DBCC CHECKIDENT (beer, RESEED, @NewSeed)
```

Here is a demonstration for your scenario.  Note that the beer_id column is created with the `IDENTITY (1, 1)` property, which seeds the identity to 1 with an increment of 1.

```
CREATE TABLE beer
    (        
    beer_id NUMERIC(10) IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    mnemonic NVARCHAR(8)
    );

GO

INSERT INTO beer(mnemonic) VALUES ('Beer 1')
INSERT INTO beer(mnemonic) VALUES ('Beer 2')

SELECT *
FROM beer ;

DBCC CHECKIDENT (beer, RESEED, 12345)
GO

INSERT INTO beer(mnemonic) VALUES ('Beer 3')
INSERT INTO beer(mnemonic) VALUES ('Beer 4')

SELECT *
FROM beer ;

DELETE
FROM beer
WHERE beer_id >= 12345 ;

DECLARE @NewSeed NUMERIC(10)
SELECT @NewSeed = MAX(beer_id)
FROM beer ;

DBCC CHECKIDENT (beer, RESEED, @NewSeed)
GO

INSERT INTO beer(mnemonic) VALUES ('Beer 5')
INSERT INTO beer(mnemonic) VALUES ('Beer 6')

SELECT *
FROM beer ;
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, looks like a complete answer. I will give this a try.

Comment: Just as an FYI, if you need to know what the current seed is you can run this `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name')`

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes we have Schema restriction from some users and thus causes error (**Cannot find a table or object with the name "TableName". Check the system catalog**), hence the best thing is to follow the below code.

Schema.TableName should be enclosed in apostrophe

```
DECLARE @SeedValue INT
SET @SeedValue = (SELECT MAX(ColumnName) FROM Schema.TableName)
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Schema.TableName',RESEED,@SeedValue)
```